# How to do enhanced\group label\hierarchical label x-axis

Tags: highcharts

I've got an interesting requirement where the labels are more than just simple labels.  I'm not sure if it is possible in Highcharts or if it is what to even call it.
.
[image: Enhanced\multi-label example]

As you can see the labels are grouped

1. Start by month
2. Days of the month (1 through 10, 11 though 20, 21-31)
3. Finally the actual date

What is the correct name for this functionality and does Highcharts even support it.  I couldn't find any information in the docs, but I'm not sure I was searching for the correct term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not directly in highcharts, it's a plugin called [Grouped categories](https://www.highcharts.com/products/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories) by Black Label

Comment: Thanks that was what I was looking for.  I don't know if I will be able to use it (because Highcharts is being used in side of another third partly application that I don't control - but can gain access if needed.)